# How to create a Modal (dialog box) using Portal using React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-dom

Hi Everyone i'm currently creating a modal which has a `Delete` and `Cancel` button. I want this modal to be reusable and this modal returns a boolean value as a promise. If ***Delete*** is pressed then ***true*** is returned and vice versa. When ***true*** is returned then the action is dispatched. I have implemented the functionality by following the steps give in the link below

https://medium.com/quadminds/react-confirm-dialog-as-service-8929c88a6702

Then implementation link is:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-confirmasservice?file=index.js

I'm new to react and currently learning react. My goal is to implement the modal using the ***ReactDOM.createPortal***.

Any help would be really appreciated. If the question seems to not describe my situation please let me know. I will try to rephrase the question.

Thank you

Comment: What on earth... The pattern you are using here is very confounding. When working with React, you should absolutely avoid these kinds of promise-based interactions, using imperative function calls like `.show`, "services", or manually creating React components by invoking their functions. One of the core principles of React is **declarative syntax**, which means that your App should rely on state, props, and an "HTML-like" structure.

Comment: Here's a simple modal hook i made. Should be easy to add your required functionality to it. https://codepen.io/jzmmm/pen/KKwjEXJ

Comment: I don't know.  Much as I like the one way data flow in react sometimes you just want an imperative dialog box.

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to implement this? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I did find the solution for this. However, have to find the solution.